# How can I add stars icons to my UITableView on the left of each row?

Tags: ios

How can I add stars icons to my UITableView like the ones in the picture ?
http://cl.ly/9bSr

They can be selected (the star icon changes and possibly the row should slide up in the first section).

How to implement it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.create custom cell
2.take one button and set its frame as your need
3.set star image as buttons background image and add button to custom cell
4.replace that cell with your existing table cell

Comment: thanks. So I've to build it. But I was wondering: isn't there a cell style (selected/unselected) I could use ?

Comment: for cell style you can use 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

and you have to manage NSMutableArray